# Affine-local property that is not stalk-local

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

From Vakil's foundations of algebraic geometry, page 158, 5.3.2"

> We say such a property is affine-local: a property is affine-local if we can check
>   it on any affine cover. (For example, reducedness is an affine-local property. Do
>   you understand why?) Note that if U is an open subscheme of X, then U inherits
>   any affine-local property of X. Note also that any property that is stalk-local (a
>   scheme has property P if and only if all its stalks have property Q) is necessarily
>   affine-local (a scheme has property P if and only if all of its affine open sets have
>   property R, where an affine scheme has property R if and only if all its stalks have
>   property Q). But it is sometimes not so obvious what the right definition of Q is;
>   see for example the discussion of normality in the next section.

He says stalk-local properties are necessarily affine local. I feel like the converse is not necessarily true but I can't come up with a counterexample. What is an affine local property that is not stalk-local?

Answer (score 3):

I think locally noetherian is such a property. A scheme is locally noetherian if and only if all of its affine opens are noetherian. But there exists a non-noetherian ring $A$ such that $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is noetherian for all prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$. An example is $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please show me how to prove $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is noetherian for $ A=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$? I guess the only possible prime ideals are zero and embeddings of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ into each component. But even so I am not sure why the localizations are noetherian.

Comment: The only possible prime ideals are ideals to satisfy $$0 \to p \to A \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \cong A/p \to 0 $$ exact. $$p$$ is prime ideal iff $$A/p$$ is integral domain.